# Django application on cpanel - increase LSAPI_CHILDREN

Tags: python, django, cpanel

I have a Django application in cpanel server,
I got this error

” Reached max children process limit: 6, extra: 2, current: 8, busy: 2, please increase LSAPI_CHILDREN. ”

What is this error?

Comment: This is unlikely to be an issue with Python or Django and probably an issue with Cpanel and your hosting https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/forum/threads/increasing-lsapi_children.14277/